# Git pull doesn't work without running ssh-add -K previously on Azure

Tags: git, azure, ssh, ssh-agent, ssh-config

My ~/.ssh/config

```
Host MyAzureAlias
  HostName ssh.myhostname.azure.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_azure_key

Host MyBitbucketAlias
  HostName bitbucket.org
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket_key
```

Then i run

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_azure_key
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket_key
```

Then i opened webstorm and opened both projects. I made pull on bitbucket. Success.
I made pull on azure and i got error: **remote: Public key authentication failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.**

Then i run**ssh -v MyAzureAlias**

And in debug i got **debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa_azure_key**

And at the end i got **debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).**

This means that my ~/.ssh/config for **MyAzureAlias** works fine.

Then i run **ssh-add -l** and it gave me my two keys.

Then i run **eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"** and then i run **ssh-add -l** again and it gave me no keys.

Then i run

- **eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"**
- **ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_azure_key**

Then **git pull** succeed.

Config:

- **macOS Catalina 10.15.4.**
- **git version 2.24.1 (Apple Git-126)**
- **ssh -V OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3**

How to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the authentication succeeds, but the Git repository access fails (on Azure), then you need to double check the URL used.

It should be:

```
git ls-remote MyAzureAlias:<me>/<myrepo>
```

Mak sure the case (lower/uper) is correct